# Hash Table with vectors, getting error for retrieving size

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, hashtable, chaining

I am adding some code to functions where in the end I have a hash table that works for separate chaining. I am trying to retrieve the size of the hash table of all the non-deleted items in the hash, which is the function `int size()`
This is the code that I think is relevant:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <stdexcept>

// Custom project includes
#include "Hash.h"

// Namespaces to include
using std::vector;
using std::list;
using std::pair;

//
// Separate chaining based hash table - inherits from Hash
//
template<typename K, typename V>
class ChainingHash : public Hash<K,V> {

    int table_size;

private:
    vector<list<V>> table;          // Vector of Linked lists

public:

    ChainingHash(int n = 11) : table(n){
    
    }

    ~ChainingHash() {
        //this->clear();
    }

    //Test for empty hash
    bool empty() {
        
        if (!table.empty()) {
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
  
    }

    //Quantity of (non-deleted) elements in hash
    int size() {
   
        int count = 0;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
            if (table[i] != nullptr) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        
        return count;
    
    }
```

I keep getting the error:

```
ChainingHash.h:65:20: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::list<int, std::allocator<int> > >, std::__cxx11::list<int, std::allocator<int> > >::value_type’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::list<int, std::allocator<int> >’} and ‘std::nullptr_t’)
   65 |       if (table[i] != nullptr) {
      |           ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/memory:62,
                 from /usr/include/gtest/gtest.h:57,
                 from test_main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:461:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator!=(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)’
  461 |     operator!=(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: please add [example]

Answer (score 0):

Compiler complain about that `List<T>` doesn't provide a comparison operator with `nullptr`, and it is not a pointer.

You can use `table[i].empty()` to know if it is empty.

You can use `erase`, to remove an element of a vector.

Answer (score 0):

For this piece of code you can use

```
int count = 0;    
for(auto i : table) ++count;
```

*This will serve your purpose*